# Possibly Error - Bug in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When i execute the query

```
select  * from Brands  where int1 = 1 and iswebactive=0 and ESHOP_CODE=1
```

in Sql Server, the server returns 2 rows.
When i execute the query

```
select  * from Brands  where isnull(int1,0) = 1 and iswebactive=0 and ESHOP_CODE=1
```

Sql server returns MORE than 2 rows. The problem is that there are 650000 records where int1=1, but the first query returns only 2 rows.
The types of fields are:

```
int1 : int
iswebactive : tinyint
ESHOP_CODE : smallint
```

Why is that happens?

---

```
select  int1,* from Brands  where int1 = 1 and iswebactive=0 and ESHOP_CODE=1
```

(returns 58 rows.)

```
select  int1,* from Brands  where isnull(int1,0) = 1 and iswebactive=0 and ESHOP_CODE=1
```

(returns 16134 rows)

The version of SQL Server is 2008 R2 Express.

My problem is that when I use `isnull` function (second query) the result is correct!

Why does the first query returns only 58 rows?

Comment: Do you have a sample row of data for the one works in the second query but not the first? AND what version of SQL including service pack are you using?

Comment: That is weird.  Having said that, do not use isnull in the where clause.  Only use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, otherwise you're asking for heartache.

Comment: You should provide us an SQLFiddle to show us off the bug

Comment: Going against my own advice, does COALESCE behave differently?

Comment: Here's a hint that will serve you well in life: "it's always your fault". It is _never_ an OS bug, or database bug, or framework bug. It's always _your_ bug.

Comment: OK.I agree with you @JohnSaunders. Can you tell me where is the wrong in 1st query and sql returns only 2 rows (and not 16000 rows which is the correct result)?

Comment: Are you running both queries as the same user, on the same server on the same database? `select @@servername, db_name(), suser_sname(), user_name()`.

Comment: Logically, those seem the same to me, although I would never suggest the second form.  Is Brands a view?  Are any of the columns computed?  Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: The Brands is not a view and the columns (which i use in the where clause) are not computed.I have triggers on the table,but the triggers are for insert,update and delete statements.

Comment: If you haven't already, go ahead and create an index on all three columns.  Also, how do the actual execution plans compare?

Comment: Also, what is the smallest amount of data where you still observe the behavior?

Comment: How many columns are in your table?  If you create a table, for testing, with fewer columns, do you still see the behavior?

Comment: I found out what was going on.... I already had indexes for these 3 columns. I found out that the index value of int1 was different from the actual value of int1. Of course when i rebuild the index everything was fine. So i suppose it wasn't my fault.It was MSSQL fault. Thank you @uncle brad for your time and your advices.

Comment: @user3013562 run DBCC CHECKDB. Corruption is usually causes by hardware errors. It will happen again for you.

Comment: @user3013562: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, do not post it only as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a Bug thing in SQL Server, at least for these types of simpler select queries. Check out your select query by break down & execute. Or may be you are having a problem with your column values simply try

```
SELECT ISNULL(COL_NAME,0) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Do this for all columns & check out the result.

Comment: This can happen if an index is corrupted. From the comments they seem to be indicating this was the case.  The `where isnull(int1,0) = 1` version would make the expression unsargable meaning that a different index is used.

Comment: Yes. But I don't think so, this is a kind of a Bug. This is due to user mistake, may disabling, dropping a constraint in SQL Server.

Comment: Corruption would probably indicate faulty or incorrectly configured hardware. Or maybe running third party buggy filter drivers or extended stored procedures rather than an actual product bug.